How i can share an instance of a class created in my FastAPI app with celery beat?
I have an app that uses websockets and I manage the connections in a python dict. Here is the code where I manage my websockets—it is running in docker containers:
ws_router = APIRouter()

class ConnectionManager:

    def __init__(self):
        self.active_sockets = {}
        self.disconnected_sockets = {}

    async def connect(self, websocket: WebSocket):
        client_ip = websocket.client.host

        self.active_sockets[websocket] = {
            "client_ip": client_ip
        }

        await websocket.send_json({
            "action": "send_id",
            "socket_id": socket_id
        })
        self.print_conn()

    def print_conn(self):
        print(f"active: {self.active_sockets}")
        print(f"disco: {self.disconnected_sockets}")

    def disconnect(self, websocket: WebSocket):

        if websocket in self.active_sockets:
            data = self.active_sockets[websocket]

            self.disconnected_sockets[data["socket_id"]] = data

            del self.active_sockets[websocket]

        self.print_conn()

    def clean_disconnections(self):
        self.print_conn()


manager = ConnectionManager()


@ws_router.websocket("/ws")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    await manager.connect(websocket)
    ping_task = asyncio.create_task(manager.enviar_ping(websocket))
    while True:
       data = await websocket.receive_json()
       await handle_data(data, websocket)

i need to use celery to clean connections, every hour, so i configured celery beat:
celery = Celery("celery")

celery.conf.broker_url = os.environ.get("CELERY_BROKER_URL")
celery.conf.result_backend = os.environ.get("CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND")
celery.conf.timezone = 'America/Mexico_City'
celery.conf.enable_utc = False
celery.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'clean_connections': {
        "task": "clean_connections",
        "schedule": crontab(minute=24),
        "options": {'queue': 'cleaner'}
    }
}

#@celery.task(name=)

@shared_task(name='clean_connections')
def clean_connections():
    manager.clean_disconnections()

When i run my project, i connect with a socket and my app log show the connections, but when celery beat is running, the celery log only shows a empty object. How can i share that memory?
I have tried to change to task and share task, and use globals but it stills print the same empty object

You might find some useful information in this answer

This is the thing with distributed architecture: since your web app and worker are not running in the same process (or necessarily even on the same machine), you can't. I can see two viable solutions here: either implement an API endpoint in your app that closes the connections, or use something that runs in the FastAPI process (something like the repeat_every function in fastapi-utils).
